# MySQL SELECT MAX(fecha) en cláusula WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas:

**customers_history** - muestra el historial de updates que se han hecho (el mismo cliente puede tener varias filas)

```
cliente_ID   |    Fecha_de_update      |     status        |         nad
-------------|-------------------------|-------------------|----------------
1            |    2016-11-17 10:33:45  |     Llamar        |         Mañana
1            |    2016-12-21 11:20:01  |     Enviar correo |         En 3 días
2            |    2016-10-10 10:25:50  |     Llamar        |         Mañana
...          |    ...                  |     ...           |         ...
```

**customers_2016** - esta tabla muestra los actuales resultados de cada cliente

```
cliente_ID        Status          nad           notas
 -------------|---------------|---------------|----------------
1             |    Null       |     Null      | He llamado, no contesta
2             |    ...        |     ...       | ...
```

Quiero hace un UPDATE en customers_2016 para incluir status y nad que se han hecho más recientemente, o sea MAX(fecha_de_update). Pero no consigo elaborar una query de MySQL. Esto es a lo que he llegado:

```
UPDATE Lithuania_customers_2016, Lithuania_customers_history

SET

customers_2016.status = customers_history.status,
customers_2016.nad = customers_history.nad

WHERE customers_2016.cliente_ID = customers_history.cliente_ID
AND MAX(customers_history.Fecha_de_update)
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE Lithuania_customers_2016, Lithuania_customers_history

SET

customers_2016.status = (

SELECT customers_history.status
FROM customers_history
ORDER BY Fecha_de_update DESC
LIMIT 1
),

customers_2016.nad = (

SELECT customers_history.nad
FROM customers_history
ORDER BY Fecha_de_update DESC
LIMIT 1
)

WHERE customers_2016.cliente_ID = customers_history.cliente_ID
```

Com `LIMIT` limitamos que solo aparezca una fila en la consulta, y al haberlo ordenado por la fecha, nos saldrá el más reciente.

Comment: He añadido WHERE cliente_id = cliente_id en cada una de los SET set clausulas SELECT y funccionó ! :) muchas gracias (tal y como me has escrito me ponen el mismo status / fecha para todos los clientes .. Pero muchas gracias por ayuda, me ha ido super bien !!! Saludos colega !

Answer (score 0):

Me ha funcionado con lo que el compañero de arriba me ha escrito, añadiendo WHERE customers_2016.cliente_id = customers_history.cliente_id. Seguro que se podría optimizar de alguna forma, porque va muy lento así, pero funciona bien.

```
UPDATE Lithuania_customers_2016, Lithuania_customers_history

SET

Lithuania_customers_2016.crm_status = (

SELECT Lithuania_customers_history.crm_status
FROM Lithuania_customers_history
WHERE Lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = Lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
ORDER BY crm_upload_date DESC
LIMIT 1
),

Lithuania_customers_2016.crm_nad = (

SELECT Lithuania_customers_history.crm_nad
FROM Lithuania_customers_history
WHERE Lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = Lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
ORDER BY crm_upload_date DESC
LIMIT 1
),


WHERE Lithuania_customers_2016.customer_db_id = Lithuania_customers_history.customer_db_id
AND Lithuania_customers_history.user_id = '100027';
```

Gracias por ayuda.